# ReflectionTypeLoadException when loading dll

Tags: c#, dll, mef

My application has ability to dynamically load modules (which are dlls) after program restart. Then each of module is running. To load module, i'm using MEF framework.

One of my module use internally databse and require such a dll's:

```
+Simple.Data.Ado.dll
+Simple.Data.dll
+Simple.Data.PostgreSql
```

this module is named

```
Storage.Simple.Data.dll
```

and provide me implementation of interface to connect to postgresql database.

However, when MEF loading dlls, just throw **ReflectionTypeLoadException**
with message

```
'GetKey' method in type 'Simple.Data.Ado.AdoAdapter' from
'Simple.Data.Ado, Version=0.12.2.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
does not have implementation.
```

I have to add that all this dll files are in the same folder and are viewable for MEF. I'm suspecting that probably I should mend this libraries.

My questions is, How could I succesfully load and use this dll, If i need to mend it, how could I do that?

Comment: This exception might be thrown in case there are some mismatches between inherited classes or interface implementations. E.g., you have an interface `IBase` with a method `IBase.Foo()`. You implement that method in your class `BaseImpl` which resides in another assembly. Then you remove this assembly from your project and add another assembly, where you implement this interface in a class `Base2Impl`. Additionally, you introduce a new method `IBase.Bar()` and implement it. But the old class does not implement this method, so an exception is thrown, since the old dll still can be discovered.